# Young Adult Fantasy book where some people, like the female protagonist with super strength, are called a special name with their special powers

Tags: story-identification, books

- **Synopsis:** Some people are born with special powers and they are called *something* in the book. The main character is one of these *something*s and their power is essentially super-strength and is the daughter of the king. Therefore, she is forced to basically do his dirty work for him. I remember that, at one point, the main character (I think her name was Kristin) falls in love with a prince (named Rowan?).
- **Genre:** Young Adult Fantasy
- **Read:** Probably 10 years ago.
- **Publication:** Also probably 10 years ago.
- **Book Details:** Hardcover, written in English

---

If I remember anything else, I'll edit it in!

Comment: Graceling. You're welcome lol.

Comment: @Adamant Dang... Put that in an answer, please! Juicy 25 reputation awaits you! :D

Comment: @Adamant Just looked it over and _Graceling_ seems right!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On the off chance Adamant did a hit and run answer comment:

[image: Book cover for *Graceling*]

*[Graceling](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3236307-graceling)* by Kristin Cashiore, first book of the *Graceling Realm* series.

> Katsa has been able to kill a man with her bare hands since she was eight—she’s a Graceling, one of the rare people in her land born with an extreme skill. As niece of the king, she should be able to live a life of privilege, but Graced as she is with killing, she is forced to work as the king’s thug.
>
> She never expects to fall in love with beautiful Prince Po.
>
> She never expects to learn the truth behind her Grace—or the terrible secret that lies hidden far away . . . a secret that could destroy all seven kingdoms with words alone.