# Book where everyone has a talent, main character can kill really well

Tags: story-identification

What is this book? I can vaguely remember it but my niece is going crazy about it.

Her direct synopsis:
"it's the one where in this world some people are born with talents and this one girl is born with the talent of being able to kill people really easily so she's taken in by the palace"

Ring any bells?

Comment: It's Graceling and it's a duplicate of another question.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/214461/51379

Comment: Trying to imagine a violent version of Xanth...

Comment: Come on, @Adamant, you know the drill. Add an answer for OP to accept or reply to.

Comment: Not the first time he's done that with this book... :-P

Comment: We do love that particular talent in our main characters.

Comment: @M. Kauf: If you believe someone has posted the correct answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting button as per the [tour].

Answer (score 8):

This is likely *[Graceling](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3236307-graceling)* by Kristin Cashiore, first book of the *Graceling Realm* series, as per the answer to [Fantasy book where some people have special powers (NOT superheroes)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/214461/fantasy-book-where-some-people-have-special-powers-not-superheroes).

[image: Book cover for *Graceling*]

> Katsa has been able to kill a man with her bare hands since she was eight—she’s a Graceling, one of the rare people in her land born with an extreme skill. As niece of the king, she should be able to live a life of privilege, but Graced as she is with killing, she is forced to work as the king’s thug.
>
> She never expects to fall in love with beautiful Prince Po.
>
> She never expects to learn the truth behind her Grace—or the terrible secret that lies hidden far away . . . a secret that could destroy all seven kingdoms with words alone.

Answer (score 1):

Are you thinking about [*Throne of Glass*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Throne_of_Glass) by Sarah J. Maas?

The main character Celaena is an Assassin brought to the palace to train with other Assassins in a Competition.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  This seems like it might fit, but with both the question and answer short on details it can be hard to tell.  You could make this a better answer by adding a few memorable points that might help trigger the OP's recognition.